# This works, but I'd like to shorten and optimize it by using def

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to optimize and shorten the code by using def when one function is put into specific point of itself. For example, after defining the apply(a,b) function, the whole apply(a,b) should put into print(b) part of apply(a,b). So far, I think recursion might be the answer to the optimization but I can't really do anything about it. Also tried apply(apply()) and everything went mixed up.(since there are many elifs in the original code) How should I optimize the this code to avoid repetition?

```
pos = ['y','Y']
def apply(a,b):
    while True:
        print(a)
        rep = input()
        if rep in pos:
            print(b)
            break

while True:
    print()
    rep = input()
    if rep in pos:        
        while True:
            print()
            rep = input()
            if rep in pos:
                print()
                break
            break
```

Comment: This code isn't working (pos undefined, indent errors). Do you have a working version to start with? If yes, could you reformat your question "this works, but I'd like to shorten and optimize ... this is my attempt that fails ..."

Comment: I fixed the syntax errors. I have my working versions but the result is in another language other than english with logical error so it wouldn't do much good:(

Comment: please you still missed a,b values

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this:

```py
pos = ['y','Y'] # is not good idea have this kind of global vars

def apply(a, b):
  print(a)
  rep = input()
  if rep in pos:
    print(b)
    return False
  return apply(a, b)

a = 'a' # define a,b
b = 'b'

apply(a, b):  # this will be executed until apply return false
```